# How to increase simultaneous remote connections in Windows 2012 Server R2

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-connection

How do you increase simultaneous remote desktop connections in Windows 2012 Server R2 edition?

We are currently limited to the default of 2 connections, but would like to increase this.  In Windows 2008 Server you would go to Admin Tools and then Remote Desktop Services, but cannot see this option in Admin Tools for Windows 2012 Server R2.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In server 2012 R2 they removed this ability without buying the licenses to make it a terminal server. they only provide the 2 "Admin" Connections and have removed the "Console" Session too.